# Installation problem with Bitcore.io on Mac

Tags: mac, bitcore

I'm normally not too brain-dead about this stuff, but I've been unable to force this one through.  I'm trying to install Bitcore (per their [instructions here](https://bitcore.io/guides/full-node)) but and have set **nvm** to the LTS version 4, as directed (v4.9.1), but when I run **npm install -g bitcore** it pukes at me:

```
/Users/evilg/.nvm/versions/node/v4.9.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1043:3
```

For what it's worth, my **npm** version is 6.2.0.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You are aware that bitcore is not Bitcoin Core, yes?

Comment: Yes, very aware.  :)

Comment: **UPDATE:**  Apparently the problem is because Mac OS doesn't support the library libunwind...      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842377/building-libunwind-for-mac#27853419 -- but I assume there's gotta be a viable workaround.  Surely all us Mac folks aren't forced to set up virtual boxes just to use Bitcore.io?